# Update old function to async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

I want to update this function to async but can't get the users object that is mapped from the interactions object to return data in the same format and my values in the async function are coming up nil client side. In the console I'm only getting the Promise object and undefined.

This is my working code:

```
Interaction.findAll({
    where: {
        targetUserId: fbId,
        status: 'invited'
    }, 
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
}).then(function (interactions) {
    Promise.all(interactions.map(interaction =>
        User.findOne({
             where: {
                 facebookUserId: interaction.userId
             },
             attributes: ['firstName', 'facebookUserId', 'pictureUrl']
    }))).then(function (users) {
    res.status(200).send(users.map(user => user.dataValues));
    })
},
```

This is what I have so far but my data isn't being returned to the client in the same format:

```
try {
    const interactions = await Interaction.findAll({
        where: {
            targetUserId: userId,
            status: 'invited'
        },
        attributes: ['lastReplyAt', 'seen', 'userId'],
    })

    const users = await interactions.map(interaction => User.findOne({
        where: {
            facebookUserId: interaction.userId
        },
        attributes: ['firstName', 'facebookUserId', 'pictureUrl'],
    }))
    res.status(200).send(users.map(user => user.dataValues));
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
}
```

If I return just the users object the error is more specific and says that 'firstName' is nil. Returning the users mapped object gives me a key error.

Comment: `interactions.map()` still returns an array, so you still need `Promise.all()` to get a promise you can await.

Comment: So simple! I love you!! @MarkMeyer Thank you so much!

Comment: await only functions when the expression after it returns a promise. the call to `map` returns an array and therefore doesn't function like you want it to. You can't really replace Promise.all with one await. Your code should look more like `await Promise.all(fn.map( ... ))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
interaction = await Interaction.findAll({
    where: {
        targetUserId: fbId,
        status: 'invited'
    }, 
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
})

users = await Promise.all(interactions.map(interaction => {
  User.findOne({
  where: {
    facebookUserId: interaction.userId
  },
  attributes: ['firstName', 'facebookUserId', 'pictureUrl']})
})

res.status(200).send(users.map(user => user.dataValues));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Many good wishes to you.